# Meteor - Constraints on package with unknown "top level"

Tags: meteor

I meet many errors like this after merging an update from my fork source:

```
No version of standard-minifier-js satisfies all constraints: @2.6.0, @~2.5.2
Constraints on package "standard-minifier-js":
* standard-minifier-js@2.6.0 <- top level
* standard-minifier-js@~2.5.2 <- top level
```

When I open `.meteor/packages`, I see only `standard-minifier-js@2.6.0`, and I don't know where the `~2.5.2` comes from. What does the message **top level** mean other than what's written in `.meteor/packages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second **top level** means meteor itself since I have downgraded meteor to 1.8.3.

`meteor update --release 1.8.3 --all-packages` fixed the problem.

Comment: Package dependencies are in `.meteor/packages`. I would want to stay on 1.10.2 and fix this - it shouldn't be too hard